# Corrupted EOF in a large gzip (2GB) file

Tags: gzip

I have a corrupted gzip file. I've read many relevant posts, and they all suggest me to unzip the file and rezip it.

I've tried commands

`gzcat`, `gzip`

I also tried to open a gzip file and write it to a new one in the Python `gzip` library.

Everything works. The above commands or the python script runs for a long time, and throws an exception at EOF.

Is there a specific way to fix corrupted EOF?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? Also, look at https://superuser.com/questions/279201/unexpected-end-of-file-gzip-compressed-file

Comment: Also, post the output from running "gunzip -t yourfile.gz"

Comment: I tried `gunzip -t`. The point is that

1. I can rezip it and pass the `gunzip -t` test, but when it comes to actually reading the file, it's not encoded correctly.

2. I can open my files, read all the lines up to the EOF. However, this option fails `gunzip -t`

So, I can either pass `gunzip -t`, but not reading the correct text file, or having a correct text file up to EOF and not passing the test.

Comment: If the original file fails the "gunzip -t" test, it means you have a truncated gzip file. That means that the end of the uncompressed data is likely to be incomplete/absent. Say the compressed data is UTF-8. If you are unlucky the uncompression will uncompress the first byte of a UTF-8 character encoding, but the subsequent bytes for that character  are absent. That means the uncompressed document is not 100% UTF-8 and so will fail because the encoding isn't valid. The best you can do in this situation is to gunzip the truncated file, remove the badly encoded data at the end and then gzip.

Answer (score 1):

Your input file is probably just truncated and thus doesn't end properly.  Any GZIP decompressor will notice an report this as a corruption of the file.  I fear there is no way to work around this situation, you *really* have lost information at the end of your file.  I only can guess on how much that is.

However, you can simply recreate a repaired compressed file out of the corrupted compressed file which contains all information which was still present in the corrupted file:

```
zcat corrupted_file.gz 2>/dev/null | gzip > repaired_file.gz
```

But of course, what's gone is gone and can't be brought back by this.  It might help you avoid trouble with other tools down your tool chain which complain about a corrupted file.

If the repaired file (which is only ›repaired‹ in terms of GZIP) lacks vital information at the end, it still might not be usable at all in your specific use case.